# Cmake: How to refer to files within an object file that is linked to multiple programs?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating some software with C++ and Cmake that I want people to be able to effortlessly build and run. Cloning the GitHub repo will install the folder `Project/`, and the code in the file `Project/src/navigation/camera/image.cpp` compiled into and linked to multiple programs all over the `Project` repository. However, inside `image.cpp` there is a path to a file `Project/Models/model.txt`, and the file path is relative to `Project/build/navigation/camera/image.o`:

**image.cpp**:

```
int processImage() {
     read_file("../../../Models/model.txt");
     // Do something
}
```

But since the object file is linked to other programs all over the project, the path should be relative to many different locations. What is the standard "Software Engineering" technique to solve this? Do you tell Cmake the path of `Project/`, and somehow let it modify image.cpp before building? Or is there a way to still use relative paths?

Comment: Are you using an in-source build model? That is with the build folder a subfolder of your source folder?

Comment: "Relative" location of a file is just wrong. In the final executable, what should be the path relative to? Relative to location of the executable? Relative to source file location? So you want "model.txt" to be in the `../../../Models` of the executable? Why not specify the path using program argument or _at least_ an environment variable? How should other people use your `Projects/Model/model.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CMake, the typical build model separates the source tree from the build tree, which means that your build folder could be anywhere relatively to the source folder. Therefore, any relative path wouldn't work reliably.

If I can't avoid having an hardcoded path in the source, my favourite solution is to pass your cpp file to the `configure` function of CMake to replace that relative path to an absolute path that CMake will calculate at generation time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "standard" this approach is, but what I would expect is a requirement that `Models` be a subdirectory of whatever directory the executable is executed from. Usually this is wherever the executable ends up, but not necessarily. For released projects, this directory is usually (expected to be) the installation directory. There is a caveat that other functions are capable of changing the current working directory, and that would make it more difficult for your code to find `model.txt`. So I would also expect a requirement that the current working directory be restored before your code is run.

If you go this route, the relative path to your data file would be `Models/model.txt`. It would be up to each project to copy this data to the appropriate directory (or create a link from the directory to the data file). Note that each project would probably want this configuration for release anyway since you usually should not (sometimes cannot) access the parent of your install directory.